# object detection model with few shot and active learning

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection, active-learning

This video https://youtu.be/60Sk-mq3Cr8, from 0 to 2:00 minutes, mentioned an object detection model that can train on 10 samples and improved over time, what kinds of the latest model out there that can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- https://paperswithcode.com/paper/you-only-learn-one-representation-unified
- https://github.com/WongKinYiu/yolor

It's an object detection model that also gives you a representation of the thing it detected that's supposed to be generally useful for new downstream tasks. 10 images isn't a lot to work with, but you could definitely try fine tuning with that data and see what happens. Start with the pre-trained weights available in the git repo.